# Regex: Combine two groups after matching a specified string

Tags: regex

String of text is in the following configurations

```html
RP0127630-001
NORTHWEST /
KMT
```

or

```html
RP0127630-001
NORTHWEST / KMT
```

What I would like to return is:

1) lookup `(?:[\w+]{2}\d{7}-\d{3}\r?\n)` = e.g. RP0127630-001 (it is always in this format but numbers could change); then

2) return in one line of string NORTHWEST-KMT (without spaces and / are converted into -)

As you can see, sometimes the string is in two lines or sometimes in one. I have tried:

```
(?:[\w+]{2}\d{7}-\d{3}\r?\n)\b(?<LineItem1Trip>(.*)\r?\n*(.*))\b
```

But I can't get the / converted into - and also to join sometimes two lines into one.

Comment: What language/tool are you using with your regex?

Comment: am actually not too sure but the software is a OCR software called scantoPDF [link](https://www.scantopdf.com/help-info/documentation/pdf-setup-guides)

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    (.*? /)\r?\n(.*?)(?=\r?\n|$)
Replace: $1 $2
```

Explanation:

```
(.*? /)      match AND capture everything up to, and including, a forward slash
             (this is NORTHWEST / in your sample text)
\r?\n        match a CR?LF
(.*?)        match AND capture the entire next line
(?=\r?\n|$)  until seeing the first CR?LF or the end of the input
```

Then, we replace those two lines with just a single line containing the capture groups.

Comment: Sorry am new to regex. With the replace function:
{Replace(LineItem1Trip,"" ,"")}
How do I use $1 and $2?

Comment: @DerrickT Try: `{Replace(LineItem1Trip,"(.*? /)\r?\n(.*?)(?=\r?\n|$)" ,"$1 $2")}` ... not sure if that will work.  If it _doesn't_, then refer to the manual or documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use your first pattern, add matching the first word on the newline and capture that in group 1. Then match the following `/` between whitespace characters and capture the following word in group 2.

Then in the replacement use the 2 capturing groups with a `-` in between.

```
(\w{2}\d{7}-\d{3}\r?\n\w+)\s*/\s*(\w+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ldsNie/1)

If using the groups in the replacement does not work, you could use lookarounds (if supported) and use only the `-` in the replacement:

```
(?<=\w{2}\d{7}-\d{3}\r?\n\w+)\s*\/\s*(?=\w+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IsYhJn/1)

Output

```
RP0127630-001
NORTHWEST-KMT

RP0127630-001
NORTHWEST-KMT
```

**Note** that in the pattern you tried, this part `[\w+]{2}` the `\w` could also match digits or an underscore instead of only uppercase chars `A-Z`

The `+` char in the character class could match the char literally.

Comment: I have been trying `(?<=\w{2}\d{7}-\d{3}\r?\n\w+)\s*\/\s*(?=\w+)`

its the closest but I only want to return NORTHWEST-KMT. In my initial attempt, I was able to get working.
RP0127630-001
NORTHWEST / KMT

But where it split into three lines I wasn't able to get it working

Comment: @DerrickT One option could be to have a second pass at it removing the first line as the change from `/` to `-` has already has been taken place. https://regex101.com/r/lcOZRU/1

Comment: Yes but it doesn't solve the issue on NORTHWEST / KMT text being on different lines. I mean it does search up the entire 2nd and 3rd line, but it doesn't return the 2nd and 3rd line into just one line

Comment: I think you can first run the first pattern which will put it in one line and then run the second pattern the remove the line before it

Comment: When I tried it on their tool, `(\w{2}\d{7}-\d{3}\r?\n\w+)\s*/\s*(\w+)` actually searches the text in three lines. There is a "reformatting expression" which as of now I only know how to use {Replace}, {RemoveChars}, {RemoveSpaces} and it seems to only understand textual based commands inside inverted commas "" and String.Empty.